# database design in nestjs microservices

Tags: authentication, nestjs, authorization, microservices

I am working on an api backend following nestjs microservice architecture, basic structure is like:

[image]

- each service send login request to authService, get token and user details; the authService also store user data in its own database;
- `UseGuards` has been implemented via tcp by use a custom `@MessagePattern({cmd:'check-user'})` in AuthService. So for ServiceA/B , routes is now under protection;

my question is : there are bunch of tables in ServiceA/B connect to user table in previous monolithic architecture (one-to-many, many-to-many,etc.). and now User table is  moved to authService , stored in different database. how can i design my database for ServiceA/B?

one idea I came realize that make copies of user tabel in ServiceA/B database, But I don't think it's a good solution for sure

what I have try:
1.each time when user login, get userid from authService, store it in ServiceA/B tables columns('userid') if the table is related to this user.(bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, solution with storing `userid` is not a bad idea. I had similar use case and used this solution. In my case, I was using JWT token to authorize and I put userId to my JWT token payload. In this case each service can work independently without needing to directly access or communicate with other services. You can include other columns of User in another services as well, but you should manage data consistency.